# df.where based on the difference of two other DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three DataFrames that are all the same shape ~(1,000, 10,000).

- `original` has ~20-100 non-zero values per row - very sparse
- `input` is a copy of `original`, with 10 random non-zero values per row changed to zero
- `output` is populated completely with non-zero values

I am now attempting to compare `original` and `output` only in the positions where `input` and `output` are different (i.e. just in the 10 randomly chosen positions)

Firstly, I create a df of only these elements of `original` with everything else set to zero:

```
maskedOriginal = original.where(original != input, other=0)
```

This is created in seconds. I then attempt to do the same for `output`:

```
maskedOutput = output.where(original != input, other=0)
```

However, since this is now working with 3 DataFrames, it is far too slow - I haven't even got a result after a couple of minutes. Is there any more suitable way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
arr = original.values
maskedOriginal = pd.DataFrame(np.where(arr != input, arr, 0), 
                              index=original.index,
                              columns=original.columns)
```

Comment: So for `maskedOutput` it would be `arr1 = original.values`, `arr2 = output.values` and `np.where(arr1 != input, arr2, 0)` ?

Comment: @KOB - Yes, if want replace one dataframe by another.

Comment: Works well, thank you. Are you able to explain why numpy can compute this no problem, but pandas can't?

Comment: @KOB - Because pandas is built on numpy arrays, so if use `numpy` functions in pandas it is the most times faster. But not all `numpy` function does not handle `NaN` values very nice, also `string`s function are poor. Another difference is numpy solutions are more complicated as pandas functions.